# How do I save the read values from my file?

Tags: c

Ok so I'm in a function which is reading in a file already created in main.  I'm supposed to calculate the number of atoms decayed per second.

So my file has values such as

```
sec  Atom
0    1000
1    900
2    830
3    754
4    543
ect.
```

What I want to do is calculate the average decayed each second.  So that the number decayed after the first second is ((1000-900)/100)*100%

My code so far is as follows.  I'm stuck on how I would save the value of 1000 and do math with it later when I get to the 2nd value.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double Average ()
{
    FILE *readfile;
    readfile = fopen("Atoms.txt","r");
    if (readfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("There was a problem opening the the output file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
int seconds;
int atoms;
int tot = 1000;
double avg;
while (fscanf(readfile,"%i %i",&seconds,&atoms)>0)
{
    avg = (double)((atoms-tot)/tot)*100;
    atoms = tot;
}
return avg;


}
```

Comment: Save it in an array?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, have you tried any solution? You say `avg = ;` and come to Stack Overflow and you're like "fix?"... or was that a typo?

Comment: We have not learned how to do that yet.  I'm just supposed to be able to do the math using the file itself.  I'm not sure if there is a way to read the previous value of the file.

Comment: `fscanf(readfile,"%i %i",seconds,atoms)>0` --> `fscanf(readfile, "%i %i", &seconds, &atoms) == 2`

Comment: I have tried a few things such as avg is (Atoms - Atoms++)/(Atoms++)*100.  Also thank you BLUEPIXY.  I forgot the pointers for a sec.

Comment: So you need to read everything from a file, display the amount of seconds, and the average OVERALL value per second that the atoms decay second to second?

Comment: I need to do it second per second.  So I need to say percentage decayed per second.

Comment: Break this problem down into steps then.

1. read through file and count amount of seconds.. put that into an int.
2. at same time as you count seconds, perform average function on what you have so far, with difference between last "Atom" value and new "Atom value"
3. display to user.

Comment: Question, does the decay always get down to 0?

Comment: Ok so I guess I just have to do the total average.  So I did that, and I'm not sure why its not working.  I figure I'm setting tot to be the 1000 atoms it starts out with.  Then it should just do the avg, and go down and set the new amount of atoms to tot.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes the decay has to do until its 0 atoms remaining.

Comment: So, if you just read the seconds and find out how many it took, and said `avg = 1000 / seconds` wouldn't that give you the avg or am i missing the point.

Comment: Yes that would be a way to do it.  I guess I thought I was just supposed to use seconds.  But yes that way does work faster.  I'm not sure if the professor would approve but I'll check.  Thanks

Comment: Another way would be to do a running average, something like...

`    while (fscanf(readfile, "%i %i", &seconds, &atoms) == 2 )
    {
        total_sec += seconds;
        total_atoms += atoms;
        avg_decay = total_atoms / total_sec;
 }`

You see what I'm saying?

Comment: comment section isn't good for blocks of code lol.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why you're setting the while statement = 2.

Comment: Definition of scanf: This function returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.